# issues having 2 reader accounts. need to log in to two different accounts

Tags: customization

I am confused. I have wordpress.com hosted by a company. When I log in to my admin account on wordpress it is different to the log in details for my wordpress reader? I have to put in different details? This results in my post fetaured images not showing on the reader. and also my media library is empty? How can I make it just the one account instead of two please?

Comment: Questions about WordPress.com are [off topic](/help/on-topic) here. You'll need to check with [WordPress.com's support team](https://wordpress.com/support/) instead.